# Mysql partial sum on rows with condition

Tags: mysql, sum, mariadb

Here is the current schema

```
StoreID | StructureID | Quota
----------------------
      1 |           1 | 100
      1 |           1 |  50
      2 |           1 | 100
      2 |           1 | 200
      3 |           1 | 100
      1 |           2 |  50
      1 |           2 |  20
      2 |           2 | 100
```

Now we should combine by adding quotas of store with the same StoreID and StructureID to become this

```
StoreID | StructureID | Quota
----------------------
      1 |           1 | 150
      2 |           1 | 300
      3 |           1 | 100
      1 |           2 | 70
      2 |           2 | 100
```

I know how to SUM() a whole table and generate a single line but not on a small part and create a partial table. Help!

A new table shall be created (`CREATE TABLE AS`) and the original table shall be untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just GROUP BY StoreID StructureID

```
SELECT StoreID, StructureID, SUM(Quota) FROM table GROUP BY StoreID, StructureID
```